# Weighted sum of a convergent series

Tags: limits, summation

what can we say about $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{ma_m}{n+1-m}$$ if $\sum |a_m|<\infty$

I seem to be a bit off here. I have a stong feeling the the limit is zero. Can someone please provide some hints. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit need not exist.

Suppose $a_{2^k} = 1/k^2$ for $k \ge 0$, $a_n = 0$ otherwise.  Then
$\sum_n a_n = \sum_k 1/k^2 < \infty$, but 
$$\sum_{m=0}^{2^k} \dfrac{m a_m}{2^k + 1 - m} \ge 2^k a_{2^k} = 2^k/k^2 \to \infty \ \text{as}\ k \to \infty$$

On the other hand, you can show that

$$\sum_{m=0}^{2^k-1}\dfrac{m a_m}{2^k - m} \to 0$$

Comment: Many thanks. This is a nice example that helped a lot. If we assume that $ma_m \to 0$ then can we then claim that the sum goes off to zero? Many thanks again!