# Weighted sum of a convergent series: Counterexample or proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to show $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{ma_m}{n+1-m}=0,$$ 
where $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|a_m|<\infty$. From a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680298/weighted-sum-of-a-convergent-series) I learnt that the summability assumption is not enough even to guarantee that this limit exists. I hence tried to impose a bit more on $a_m$. So far I can show that the above limit is zero if $m^{1+\alpha}a_m\to 0$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Can I then show the same if $m a_m \to 0$? Or is there a counter example?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea may be to use a $L^1-L^{\infty}$ interpolation inequality, like:

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{m a_m}{n+1-m} \leq \left(\sum_{m\leq n/2}a_m\right)\max_{m\leq n/2}\frac{m}{n+1-m}+\left(\max_{n/2\leq m\leq n} ma_m\right)\sum_{n/2\leq m\leq n}\frac{1}{n+1-m} $$
but the last term is essentially $\left(\max_{n/2\leq m\leq n} ma_m\right)\log(n)$, that can be troublesome.

For instance, $a_m = \frac{1}{m\log(m+2)}$ satisfies $ma_m\to 0$ but not $\sum |a_m|\leq +\infty$.

> We may tweak it a bit by setting:
>   $$ a_n = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}\frac{1}{n\log(n+2)} & \text{if } n=2^{k},\;k\in\mathbb{N} \\ \frac{1}{n\log^2(n+2)} & \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$$
>   That gives a counter-example to your conjecture.

Comment: looks great! many thanks! +1